# Java Font.createFont fails on Linux because of sun.misc.IOUtils.createTempFile("+~JF", ".tmp", null)

Tags: java, swing, fonts, privileged-functions

I've some code that ultimately calls  `Font.createFont`. It works fine on server (centos something...) but on my Ubuntu box it dies because of this call that is inside `Font.createFont`

```
final File tFile = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction<File>() {
                    public File run() throws IOException {
                        return sun.misc.IOUtils.createTempFile("+~JF", ".tmp", null);
                    }
                }
            );
```

My `/tmp` dir is readable/writable by the entire world. No idea why this is happening.

Comment: Try printing out the `java.io.tmpdir` system property to ensure the JVM has picked up the correct path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was simply failing because my tomcat installation didn't have a `temp` directory. Creating the directory just solved the problem. :)